# Варианты верстки обычного wrap фрагмента

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, sass

В макете есть секция, которую, конечно, есть много способов сверстать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сверстал это следующим образом:

SASS:

```
.skills
    &__title
        margin-bottom: 93px
    &-wrap
        display: flex
        justify-content: space-between
        align-items: center
        flex-wrap: wrap
        margin-bottom: 115px
        &__item
            text-align: center
            flex-basis: 25%
        &__image
            margin-bottom: 24px
    &__button
        display: block
        margin: auto
        padding: 23px 59px
```

HTML:

```
<section class="section skills">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="section__title skills__title">Что я делаю</h2>
        <div class="skills-wrap">
            <div class="skills-wrap__item">
                <div class="skills-wrap__image"><img src="img/skills/landing.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="skills-wrap__text"><span>Вёрстка лендинг–страниц
                        и сайтов любой сложности</span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skills-wrap__item">
                <div class="skills-wrap__image"><img src="img/skills/responsive.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="skills-wrap__text"><span>Адаптивная вёрстка под все
                        браузеры и устройства</span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skills-wrap__item">
                <div class="skills-wrap__image"><img src="img/skills/programming.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="skills-wrap__text"><span>Frontend–разработка
                        и программирование</span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skills-wrap__item">
                <div class="skills-wrap__image"><img src="img/skills/correction.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="skills-wrap__text"><span>Исправление и доработка
                        существующей вёрстки</span> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="button skills__button">Узнать стоимость</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Этот вариант не кажется мне совсем правильным, так как, как минимум я не понимаю, как ограничить свой span в ширине, чтобы текст был именно как по макету.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И того у меня возникают 2 вопроса:

1) Как это лучше сверстать? Есть ли в моем варианте какие-то существенные недочеты? Задумываюсь насчет margin-right каждому блоку, нужно ли его задать каждому item? Если да, то что стоит подкорректировать?

2) Как правильно ограничить span по ширине, чтобы текст был как по макету?

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение - расставить по текстам в `span` неразрывные пробелы:

```
<span>Вёрстка лендинг–страниц и&nbsp;сайтов любой сложности</span>
```

По дизайну не ясно что будет с макетом, если ширина страницы увеличится/уменьшится. Если нужно сохранять форматирование как есть, я бы зафиксировал ширину блоков.